# Accessing a local website from another computer inside the local network in IIS 7

Tags: iis, networking, iis-7, localhost

Ok, so here is the scenario:

I have **computer A** inside my local network running IIS 7. I added a new website, let's say samplesite.local, through IIS Manager, and edited the **hosts** file inside %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\ with this new line:

127.0.0.1    samplesite.local

So, in a browser running in computer A, if I type samplesite.local in the address bar and hit Enter, **everything works fine**. I can access the website.

Now I wanted to access this website from other local computers, say, **computer B** or an **iPad**, not from the outside world, but from inside the same local network.

Any thoughts?

**Edit:**
Computer A's IP is 192.168.1.100, and samplesite.local is running on port 80. However, if I type 192.168.1.100 in any computer's browser's address bar, I'm taken to the default IIS website, the one with the IIS logo, whose physical address is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\, not to samplesite.local.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have the same problem

Comment: @Jackson You might not need to do anything, since you are using the same network. Maybe, the best way to check, is from the hosting machine, switch off the windows firewall, and try to access again

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Add two bindings to your website, one for local access and another for LAN access like so:

Open IIS and select your local website (that you want to access from your local network) from the left panel:

> Connections > server (user-pc) > sites > local site

Open **Bindings** on the right panel under **Actions** tab
add these bindings:

1. Local:

   > ```
   > Type: http
   > Ip Address: All Unassigned
   > Port: 80
   > Host name: samplesite.local
   > ```
2. LAN:

   > ```
   > Type: http
   > Ip Address: <Network address of the hosting machine ex. 192.168.0.10>
   > Port: 80
   > Host name: <Leave it blank>
   > ```

Voila, you should be able to access the website from any machine on your local network by using the host's LAN IP address (192.168.0.10 in the above example) as the site url.

**NOTE:**

if you want to access the website from LAN using a host name (like samplesite.local) instead of an ip address, add the host name to the hosts file on the local network machine (The hosts file can be found in **"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"** in windows, or **"/etc/hosts"** in ubuntu):

> 192.168.0.10 samplesite.local

Comment: What to do, if the website isn't located inside `wwwroot` folder. Like it's been running using **Visual Studio**

Comment: Can I access using different port? e.g. 192.168.0.10:8000

Comment: Yes, just open the port on the firewall of web server, then add port 8080 to the end of the address, just like your example: 192.168.20.22:8080

Comment: Hi can anyone tell me if it is possible to use the hostname to access the website from a local area network. Say like a different computer on the local network? If possible please let me know how.

Comment: my machine remote pc just keeps resolving to "localhost" :(

Comment: Hi, can i access local with domain from other computer?

Comment: I ran asp.net core 5 web api in vs 2019 with `"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/"`, bit I still see "Bad request-invalid hostname", when go to *computer ip*/*pagename* by my phone in one local network.

Comment: after adding ip and hostname in host file still unable to access on another computer with same LAN with host name? (with IP it is working). Any other solution?

Answer (score 28):

do not turn off firewall,
Go Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall then Advanced settings then Inbound Rules->From right pan choose New Rule-> Port-> TCP and type in port number 80 then give a name in next window, that's it.

Answer (score 13):

Control Panel >> Windows Firewall

Advanced settings >> Inbound Rules >> World Wide Web Services - Enable it All or (Domain, Private, Public) as needed.

Comment: Can you go into more detail on why and how this resolves the issue and especially what "as needed" would be in the actual case?

Comment: I was struggling making my local machine IIS available to other machine on my network, so this is what I did to get it resolved after verifying with my admin. I tried some of the other solution on the blog and it didn't work for me so I wanted to share my solution.  So my basic understanding is in order to access to your any inbound request to your machine it has to go through firewall unless its disabled. In my situation since I wanted access IIS to I only enabled my IIS to be available on my network. There are other solutions that made sense but didn't work for me.

Comment: I had this in Windows 10. The issue was the 'domain' firewall, for which the setting has moved. I had to go 'Start' > type "Windows Defender Settings" > Firewall and Network Protection, then turn off 'Domain network'. Even though I had opened port 80, this still needed doing to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Find the local IP address of computer A and find the port that your website is running on. Then from computer B open a web browser and go to IP:port. Example: 192.168.1.5:80 if computer A's IP is 192.168.1.5 and your website is running on port 80

Comment: how if I want access as domain e.g example.com from computer B (client) ?

Answer (score -6):

Control Panel >> Windows Firewall >> Turn windows firewall on or off >> Turn off.

Advanced settings >> Domain profile >> Windows firewall properties >> Firewall status >> Off.

Comment: this can solve the issue but it is not recommended to turn the firewall off

Comment: can try adding inbound rules

Comment: While it's a bad idea to leave the firewall down - this helped me at least narrow down what the issue was.  Now to do as @VijayKumbhoje suggested and mess with the inbound rules.