# Connect to local IIS from Android Emulator (not IIS Express)

Tags: android, iis, xamarin, android-emulator

From an android emulator, is there any way to connect to a locally hosted site in IIS which is not hosted under default website or running in IIS Express?

I have read about the loopback address from the emulator to localhost and indeed this works to the following as it sits as a site under default web site in IIS

- http://10.0.2.2/devtpservice/core/authenticationservice.svc

However, i need to connect to the service which is not hosted under default website.

- http://devtpservice.com/Core/AuthenticationService.svc

The above url results in 'net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED'

[image: IIS Config]

Comment: Are you able to access the IIS server from the another machine on same network. It's common problem discussed here in this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/21896534/85606

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks Prashant C for the pointer. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26599826/240390)