# Accessing a local website from another computer inside the local network in IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, iis, web

On my computer I have deployed my web site on IIS. If I access this website locally with :8080 works perfect, but when I try to access this site from another machine or my Android phone I get 'The site can't be reached. my_ip_address took too long to respond ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT –' this error.

I have tried solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896534/accessing-a-local-website-from-another-computer-inside-the-local-network-in-iis), but nothing worked for me. Need some help!

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network

Comment: Didn't help me.

Comment: What url you are using to access your site from different machine/android phone?

Answer (score 1):

There are few factors which can affect the accessibility of the site hosted on your local computer:

- Is the client machine (including your phone) in the same network as the Server (In this case your site)
- Is the firewall configured to allow connections on port 8080
- Have you tried accessing the server using the IP Address. For e.g. http://192.168.0.1:port

**Steps to isolate**

- Ping the server Ip from the client machine and see if it is able to connect to it.

> `ping 192.168.0.1`

If the above fails, then I would assume that you are not on the same network. If it succeeds then check if the port is open.

You can also use [nmap](https://nmap.org/) to see whether the ports are open or not

> `nmap -p 8080 kaushal.com`

If the above fails, then open the port in your **Firewall** configuration and then try again.

Try this and share the results.